# The property height is not recognized by Google for an object of type Distance

Tags: html, schema.org, structured-data

Given a visual art work that's 18 x 24 inches:

```
<div itemscope="itemscope" itemtype="http://schema.org/VisualArtwork">
  <span itemprop="height" itemscope="itemscope" 
    itemtype="http://schema.org/Distance">18 inches</span>
  <span itemprop="width" itemscope="itemscope" 
    itemtype="http://schema.org/Distance">24 inches</span>
</div>
```

This markup fails the [Structured Data Testing Tool](https://developers.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool/) with the error, "The property *height* is not recognized by Google for an object of type *Distance*." Same goes for *width*.

Interestingly enough, if you plug the first example from Schema.org for [VisualArtwork](https://schema.org/VisualArtwork) (the one about the Magritte painting) into the SDTT you get the same errors. Is the Testing Tool mistaken about this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest using [Quantitative Value] instead of [Distance].  Here's a basic example:

```
<div itemscope="itemscope" itemtype="http://schema.org/VisualArtwork">
  <span itemprop="height" itemscope="itemscope" itemtype="http://schema.org/QuantitativeValue">
    <span itemprop="value">18</span> 
    <span itemprop="unitCode" content="INH">inches</span>
  </span>
  <span itemprop="width" itemscope="itemscope" itemtype="http://schema.org/QuantitativeValue">
    <span itemprop="value">24</span> 
    <span itemprop="unitCode" content="INH">inches</span>
  </span>
</div>
```

I've given some additional information about this in my blog post at http://www.lazaruscorporation.co.uk/blogs/arts-tech/posts/schema-dot-org-quantitative-value-accessibility-typography

I'll have a look at the examples on schema.org and correct them if necessary (I was the person who wrote those examples!)

Paul